# [SOLVED]iis rewrite rule fails when www is omitted

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I have searched Stackoverflow extensively. None of them are working for my problem.

Problem:
I have a dummy website hosted on local machine with hostname: gateway.com on port 443 (self signed cert) and also i have hosted a private website on localhost:9443 with same signed cert.

Below is the webconfig rewrite rule i have added for gateway.com.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Reverse proxy to SAP" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^sap/(.*)"/>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:9443/sap/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"  logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
                </rule> 
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

The idea here is that; whenever i hit https://gateway.com/sap/getsomething; it should rewrite to https://localhost:9443/sap/getsomething

The above rule is working perfectly fine when i use https://www.gateway.com/sap/getsomething
but it fails if i omit www.

Kindly please help.

Thanks

Note: Solved it. It was a DNS correction required in hosts file as well as hostname in website config in IIS. My VM where i was testing was having issue.

Comment: This problem may be caused by DNS, because you rewrite to localhost, which may only match www in your DNS, so please check your DNS configuration.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I changed DNS and still no luck

Comment: Can you show me your DNS configuration?

Comment: Sorry you were right initially. Finally figured out that the VM i was using was having corrupt IIS which wasnt working fine. I tested in 2 new VMs; and all fine. Yes DNS in hosts file as well as hostname in website was having www. hence this problem. 
Thanks